# Set Theory, Universal set and complement of set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ , $B=\{2,4,5\}$ and $\Omega=\{x: x \text{ is a digit}\}$, find
>
> 1. $A'-B'$,
> 2. $(A-B)'$,
> 3. $(A \cap B)'$.

Here I don't understand how to find the complements.

Please reply.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Please provide more detail

Comment: I can't able to find complement

Comment: Because for complement we need universal set

Comment: I know universal set minus set A gives complement of set A but here it is really difficult to find universal set please help me

Comment: But you **do** have the universal set, it is right there in the problem statement. See that funny letter that looks like a horseshoe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The universal set is $\Omega = \{x:x \text { is a digit}\} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

The complement of $A = \{1,2,3\}$ is the set obtained considering all elements of $\Omega$ that are not in $A$, hence $A' = \{ 0,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$.

Try, with the same reasoning, to find the complement of $B$.

Comment: But universal set is  till 9 why?   Because x is a digit means infinite 11,2,3,4,..........to infinite. Why you take till 9.  Please explain

Comment: I understand the process but the problem is that    why you define universal set till 9 only not more that that.  Please explain

Comment: In the decimal system, digits are the "building blocks", the numbers 1-9. 11 is a natural number, but not a digit (it's made out of two digits, 1 and 1).

Comment: Thank you so much for you support

Comment: You're welcome. Next time you ask a questions and write comments try to be more specific about your doubts, and give us the time to write, don't re-comment immediately :)

Comment: Now, i understand completely thanks once again.

Comment: Ok,  sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what a "Digit" is?  (Interesting that you chose that user name!)  The problem said $\Omega= \{x| x$ is a digit$\}$.  That is the "universal set", {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}.

Comment: Yes, thank you helping.  I choose this name so that I remember digit forever.